# crosswalk-project error ' Building ABI 'armeabi-v7a' failed'

Tags: android, phonegap-build, hybrid-mobile-app, ubuntu-16.04, crosswalk-project

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 and crosswalk-project with Phonegap/Cordova to make my hybrid app. I'm compiling the exemple: https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/android/build_an_application.html And i got this error:

[image: image description here]

I 'googled' about this error and I founded nothing to solve me. What it says?

Answer (score 2):

You should check the build logs.
In my case everything was pretty simple. I forgot to put icon.png that was specified in manifest.json.

Comment: Definitely check about the icon / name of the icon

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you did't install latest sdk. I think it pick for default build the latest sdk. So you can see additional options using:

```
crosswalk-pkg help
```

and build with optional target sdk.