# crosswalk packaging failed *** ERROR: Building ABI 'armeabi-v7a' failed

Tags: android, windows, phonegap-build, hybrid-mobile-app, crosswalk

I am trying to package my WebGL game using **crosswalk-pkg**, but it always fails when it starts building **armeabi-v71** (screenshot is attached).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QB8Mo.jpg

I tried to find this error on Google and StackOverflow, but it looks like it is only me who is facing this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I update the Java SDK to 1.8.0_111 x86 version and the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

solved pointing `manifest.json` to an existing icon.
source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40366767/382515